# My NFC Scan application starts only if NFC Type 2

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I've made an NFC application who can reads NFC tag. It works well. (With all types)

But since yesterday i'm trying to start automatically my app once a NFC tag is maintained against my device.

So i've updated my Manifest :

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
```

Then, here is my nfc_tech_filter.xml

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

And surprise, it works only when I hold a NFC Type 2 against my device.
I've try with my appartement key (Mifare Classic) and my bank card (IsoDep), and it doesn't launch my app...
I specify that it works when my app is already started.

Any idea?

**EDIT :**

This is my Manifest right now :

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
```

Now, when I pass my bank card, it opens the application but doesn't display any result.

```
Parcelable[] rawMessages =
                    intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

rawMessages variable is NULL after that. Same if I put NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES

Comment: Are you sure they are not responding to the other intent filter `NDEF_DISCOVERED` and don't have a data scheme of a url (`http`) therefore doesn't open?

Comment: No, I've console.logged the intent and it seems that he is responding to `TAG_DISCOVERED `

Take a look : 
`Intent { act=android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED flg=0x30000000 hwFlg=0x100 cmp=com.example.senzu/.MainActivity (has extras) }`

EDIT : That's when I try with a IsoDep tag

Comment: Your Bank Card won't be storing NDEF messages, it will have it's own specific Format and APDU command set, which unless you are reading this as well then the expected result would be to start your App and do nothing.

Comment: Thanks! and what about Mifare Classic?

Comment: It is possible to store NDEF data on a Mifare Classic Card, but from memory this is a vendor specific implementation and not a NFC standard therefore I believe that Android does not support it directly (you can implement it yourself thought). Most Mifare Classic Card won't have NDEF data on them.

Comment: Yes but when I scan my Mifare Classic Card when my app is already opened, it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED:
>
> This intent is started if no activities handle the ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED or ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED intents.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc

You get this Intent when no others has captured it, so there is something wrong in your setup.

You can capture it explicitly like:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information ! 

About the manifest, I've updated my main post :)

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and your next question (about data from the different NFC devices) should be a new stackoverflow question.